# Extract and evaluate range from a give range string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a table in which products are stored. Below is the schema with data.

[image]

What I want to achieve is that I will pass ProductId, Tenure and Range as parameters and it will pick matched record.

So for example, If I have my Parameters  `ProductId = 21`, `Tenure=Duration=1` , and `Range =14678` , then it should give me `Id=4` as my expected output. Because the range is given 10001-15000.

Comment: Aside: `Price_Range` should really be two columns, e.g. `MinPrice` and `MaxPrice`. That way they can both be a suitable numeric data type and you don't have to dance around problems like negative values, e.g. `'-30 - -15'`, which no one expected oil futures to hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parsename()` in concert with a `try_convert()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[ProductID] int,[Price_Range] varchar(50),[Duration] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,21,'0 - 5000',1)
,(2,21,'5001 - 10000',1)
,(4,21,'10001 - 15000',1)
,(5,21,'15001 - 20000',1)
 
Select * 
 From @YourTable
 Where ProductID = 21 
   and Duration  = 1
   and 14678 between try_convert(int,parsename(replace(Price_Range,'-','.'),2))
                 and try_convert(int,parsename(replace(Price_Range,'-','.'),1))
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ProductID   Price_Range     Duration
4   21          10001 - 15000   1
```

**Note:**  The `try_convert()` may not be necessary.  Not knowing the full scope of your data, it best to avoid false positives.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `parsename()` for such purposes is icky -- clever, but icky.  SQL Server really should provide the appropriate functions.

So, I would use:

```
14678 >= try_convert(int, left(price_range, charindex(' ', price_range))) and
14678 <= try_convert(int, stuff(price_range, 1, charindex('-', price_range) + 1, ''))
```

Comment: "icky" ... is that the technical term ?  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . .I also admit it's clever.

Comment: Just having a little fun with you.